# Xcode 4.5 takes longer to run app on device with iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Has anyone else noticed that it seems to take much longer to "send" an app from Xcode to run it on a device? I'm seeing new delays of many seconds while it goes over to an iOS 6 device.

Is there anything that can be configured to improve this loading time, or is it due to some new stuff going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It's a reasonable question about the iOS development environment.

Comment: I disagree, but I didn't DV. Its far too subjective to be a answerable question.

Comment: The measurement of time in seconds is not a subjective data set.

Comment: Is it much longer ? You could check the Console (both device and dev machine), maybe something goes wrong. PS Upvoted to compensate uncommented downvote.

Comment: But the comparison is. There's no real benchmarks that can be done here, as many things could be influencing the deploy time.

Comment: thanks @A-Live I'm just noticing that with the same apps, same source code, pressing the Run button in Xcode to send to an iPhone or iPad is a much longer process (wait time) than prior to the iOS 6 sdk. Looks like no one has any suggestions but I still thought it was a good thing to inquire about.

Comment: I've had this feeling as well but just assumed that more was going on behind the scenes. I don't find it an issue though.

Comment: well i have faced the same thing specially when deploying to a 3GS, it can take up to a minute and gets very frustrating to debug on that device.

Comment: agree @KDaker it's a shame the question was closed when several people seem to want answers on this.

Comment: I have not experienced any delay of compiling or copying the app to the device... it is interesting.

Comment: Upvoted. On *a specific project* with iPad only, I'm getting 30-60 second delay on every Run.

Comment: Ironically, Stack Overflow just awarded me the "Nice Question" badge for this question, even though 4 people voted to close it. However, it appears it has now been re-opened.

Comment: and... it's been closed again.